# Obtaining "consensus" results from two different files using awk

Tags: awk, compare, consensus

I have `file1` as a result of a first operation, it has the following structure

```
201            12               0.298231           8.8942
206            13               -0.079795           0.6367
101            34               0.86348           0.7456
301            15               0.215355           4.6378
303            16               0.244734           5.9895
```

and `file2` as a result of a different operation and has the same type of structure.

File 2 sample

```
204            60               -0.246038           6.0535
304            83               -0.246209           6.0619
101            34               -0.456629           6.0826
211            36               -0.247003           6.1011
305            83               -0.247134           6.1075
206            46               -0.247485           6.1249
210            39               -0.248066           6.1537
107            41               -0.248201           6.1603
102            20               -0.248542           6.1773
```

I would like to select fields 1 and 2 that have a field 3 value higher than a **threshold** in file1 (0.8) , then for these selected values of field 1 and 2, select the values that have a field 3 value higher than another **threshold** in file 2 (abs(x)=0.4).

Note that although files 1 and 2 have the same structure fields 1 and 2 values are **not the same** (not the same number of lines etc..)

Can you do this with `awk`?

desired output 
101            34

Comment: So what is the threshold value and you need to post a sample of file2.

Comment: I added a samplpe of file 2 (although it's not in table form when I save my edit) , the value of the threshold doesn't really matter, what matters is that the two thresholds can be different.

Comment: You question makes it sound like the threshold is picked up from the file contents, Is this not the case? Are the thresholds just parameters?

Comment: Whats your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

If you combine awk with unix commands you can do the following

`sort file1.txt > sorted1.txt` 
`sort file2.txt > sorted2.txt`

Sorting will allow you to use JOIN on the first line (which I assume is unique). Now field 3 of file1 is $3 and file2 is $6. Using awk you can write the following.:

`join sorted1.txt sorted2.txt | awk 'function abs(value){return (value<0?-value:value);}{print $1"\t"$2} $3 >=0.8 && abs($6) >=0.4'`

In essence, in the awk you first write a function to deal with absolute values, then you simply ask it to print line 1 and 2 selecting for the criteria you detailed at $3 and $6 (formely field 3 of file1 and file2 respectively)

Hope this helps...